# What does NAM means in this sentence?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

> IULIUS SOLUS NON EST, NAM QUATTUOR SERVI APUD EUM SUNT.

> MEDUS NON EST APUD DOMINUM, NAM IS DOMINUM IRATUM TIMET.

From what I can assume it means something like *because*? But I am not sure since earlier in the book the word QUIA was suppose to mean *because*.

Also, why they use APUD instead of CUM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Nam* means something like "for" or "because" or "since"; it indicates that what comes next is an explanation of what came before. So in this case, Julius isn't alone, *since* four slaves are with him. Medus isn't with the lord, *because* he's afraid of the lord [when he's] angry.

*Quia* also means "because", but I understand *quia* as a reason more than an explanation; you wouldn't use *quia* unless you were giving the specific reason for some event, but you could use *nam* for any sort of clarification. The difference isn't huge, and you could just as well use *quia* in the second sentence here, for example: being afraid of the master is the reason Medus is avoiding him.

For your second question, *apud* is more about being in the vicinity of something or someone, while *cum* is about accompanying or being alongside them. But again the difference isn't huge, and you could say the slaves were *cum eō* in the first sentence with no significant change in meaning; if Julius isn't alone not alone, presumably the slaves are both "near" him and "accompanying" him.